# Change "Date Added" Field based on values in another field

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm just learning Microsoft Access, and I'm trying to write an update query that will change the field "Date Added" to a certain date based on another field called "Plant".  Example: If Plant for a record = "MP", then change [Date Added] to 6/1/2013

The problem is that the values in the Plant field range from NULL to MP18, and the years need to match.  I've looked at nested IIF statements, but I don't have any experience with SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new table along with Plant & the corresponding dates.
2. Link the tables via plant and write a query to update date

---

**Main Table**

[image]

**Table with Criteria**

[image]

**Update Query**

```
Update tblExample as a INNER JOIN tblChange as b ON a.plant = b.plant
set a.[date added]= b.[date added]
where years = 2018
```